# Windows Phone 8: How to remove the delay of a Pivot control?

Tags: windows-phone-8, pivot

I want to use the Pivot control in my Windows Phone 8 app. It all works great except for one little detail... it seems to have delay when I swipe between pivot items.
To explain what I am talking about. Please compare the following:

1. In Visual Studio, create a new project based on the "Windows Phone Pivot App" template. Run this on a device or in the emulator. Swipe left or right a couple of times.
2. Now open up the settings app or the native mail app on Windows Phone 8. Those apps use a Pivot as well. Now swipe left or right a couple of times again. Notice how fast new content is displayed every time you swipe!

So basically: I want to remove the "delay" I experience when using the stock Pivot control and instead have the same speed as the settings and mail app.

Can anyone help me out please?

Comment: The native apps are not written in Silverlight, and this is not a question that can be given a absolute answer.

Comment: I did not know that... I have downloaded many apps from the Store and none of them have a fast-scrolling Pivot control. They're all as slow as mine. I guess you're right. Why didn't they eat their own dog food when they created the native apps? Lame!